# Convert Date to a string of "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+HH:MM" format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to convert a Date to a string in the `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+HH:MM` format.
I know how to get it into `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ` or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ` format, but not with the `+HH:MM`.
How do I do so?

Comment: Consider using monent.js

Comment: By not showing any explicit code, you reduce your hopes of having an answer... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the offset that you are expecting to have displayed? In JS a Date is held as a UTC date, with no offset. The offset is relevant only when you want to indicate the local time in a specific timezone. Is it the timezone of the computer on which your app is running or the timezone of a remote user in some other location?